# Suppress default text in tooltip using plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly

With plot_ly(), I am able to add what I want in the tool tip, but I don't manage to get rid of the default value. Is there way to do this ?

In the example below, for the first point, the tooltip is "250 company1". I would like to get only "company1". I have a solution using ggplot2 and then ggplotly() with the tooltip option, but I would rather remain with plotly only.

```
require(plotly)

seq <- 1:10
name <- c(paste0("company",1:10))
value <- c(250,125,50,40,40,30,20,20,10,10)
d <- data.frame(seq,name,value)
plot_ly(data=d,x=seq,y=value,text=name)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the `hoverinfo` parameter for `plot_ly`:

```
seq <- 1:10
name <- c(paste0("company",1:10))
value <- c(250,125,50,40,40,30,20,20,10,10)
d <- data.frame(seq,name,value)
plot_ly(data=d,x=seq,y=value,text=name,hoverinfo="text")
```

More reading: [plotly R chart attribute reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter)

Comment: That works great. Thanks! However, when I specify `size = something` in the `plot_ly` options, it still shows up in hover text, even if the hover text I am specifying does not have that part. Thoughts?

Comment: Here you are @Gopala: `plot_ly(data = d, type = "scatter", x = seq, y = value, text = name, hoverinfo = "text", marker = list(size = seq))`.

Answer (score 1):

Gopala, I asked a similar question and found the answer useful. Perhaps it will help you too.

[How can I remove the size line in the hoverinfo of a Plotly chart in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596849/how-can-i-remove-the-size-line-in-the-hoverinfo-of-a-plotly-chart-in-r)